# Need help for identifying common rows based on multiple column match data in 2 excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 excel files. I want to compare the sheet1 of file-1 and sheet1 of file2 and then get all the common/matching rows. Rows in 2 separate files can be in different row positions

1st XL file

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
11      role11  name12
22      role21  text22
33      role31  name32
55      role49  name69
```

2nd XL File

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
11      role11  name12
33      role31  name36
55      role45  name69
22      role21  text22
```

So the end result should be matching rows i.e as below

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
11  role11  name12
22  role21  text22
```

Comment: Why don't you just filter one table using [**Advanced Filter**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bkmk_0) using the second table as the advanced filter criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Using **`Excel Formulas`** you could try something like this:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K3</kbd>

```
=FILTER(A3:C6,1-ISNA(XMATCH(A3:A6&"|"&B3:B6&"|"&C3:C6,F3:F6&"|"&G3:G6&"|"&H3:H6)))
```

---

- So the `XMATCH()` function returns the position of the matching rows, note that i have concatenated the cells/ranges using a `|` so to avoid any `FALSE Positives` --> `=XMATCH(A3:A6&"|"&B3:B6&"|"&C3:C6,F3:F6&"|"&G3:G6&"|"&H3:H6)`
- Then wrapped within `ISNA()` to get those not matched and subtracting it by `1` also we can use `ISNUMBER()` instead of this but i see there are some less characters being used, hence which returns `TRUE` instances --> `=1-ISNA(XMATCH(A3:A6&"|"&B3:B6&"|"&C3:C6,F3:F6&"|"&G3:G6&"|"&H3:H6))`
- Lastly using the `FILTER()` function extracting the one which is included here, i.e. the one which is `TRUE`.

---

Or, `COUNTIFS()` function can be used with `FILTER()` as well:

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(F3:H6,COUNTIFS(A3:A6,F3:F6,B3:B6,G3:G6,C3:C6,H3:H6))
```

---

Or Using `POWER QUERY` which is available from `Excel 2010+` onwards Windows and MAC.

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1st` & `Table_2nd`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1st"]}[Content],
    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2nd"]}[Content],
    MergeData = Table.NestedJoin(SourceOne, {"ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC"}, SourceTwo, {"ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC"}, "SourceTwo", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded SourceTwo" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeData, "SourceTwo", {"ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC"}, {"ColumnA.1", "ColumnB.1", "ColumnC.1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded SourceTwo", each [ColumnA.1] <> null and [ColumnA.1] <> ""),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

**Notes:** Change cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit, also if using `POWER QUERY` then make necessary changes to the tables names as per your preferences.